# django - re-running migration that creates constraints and fails halfway

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have a migration that adds a bunch of `unique_together` constraints. When I execute it, it fails halfway because some tables don't respect this constraint. So I have to go in and fix the data, and then run the migration again.

Problem is that when I try to run it again, it complains that the constraints already exist

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '406-14933' for key 'app_model_language_id_category_id_29dac763_uniq'")
```

This happens in tables in which there was no problem in the previous run, hence the constraint was created. Then I have to go in and delete the constraint by hand, and then I can run it again.

Is there a way to just let it ignore this error and continue?

Comment: You’re using MySQL right?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes

Comment: Probably you can fake that migration: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake

Comment: You cannot ignore the error, otherwise the unique constraint would not be unique. You need to create a migration with a RunPython command that deletes the offending rows and run that migration before the one that adds the constraints

Comment: I can't make a migration because the data merging is a very manual procedure. Since apparently there is a unique identifier for this constraint (29dac763 in this case), I thought it could be either deleted and created or not created again.

Comment: You could fake the migration and add the indexes yourself with `IGNORE` - `ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE INDEX myindex (A, B, C, D);
 `. This will delete data though

Comment: deleting data is not an option

Comment: the obvious answer came to me just after I finished with not few manual constraint deletions going back and forth !! it is to make many migrations of one constraint each only. So either the constraint will fail and not be created, or not fail and not needed to recreate next time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can bypass this check, so the way to go about this is instead of creating one migration that creates many constraints and could fail halfway, create many migrations of only one constraint each. Then if one table is correct, the constraint is created and you can go to the next and never come back to this one.